# Display Discontinuous Line chart in iOS Charts

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I am using iosCharts Framework for desiging Line and Bar charts in iOS application.

I have a requirment of displaying the discontinuous line chart.

Is it possible in iOSCharts framework. If Yes can any one provide me the solution.